# Clear Controls In modalpopupextender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a GridView with hyperlinks and on the hyperlink click a Modal Popup Extender pops up. There are textboxes that are shown or hidden based on what row on the GridView got clicked. My issue is when the Modal Popup Fires and users fill out the texboxes and lets say they click close and I hide the Modal Popup Extender when they click on a  different GridView row or the same one the previous data appears. Seems like the Modal Popup Extender does not clear Controls under it. I tried setting my UpdatePanel to conditional and forcing the update that did not work. Please help I have been trying to figure this out for couple of days now and its getting really annoying. Thanks for your help.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div>     
            <asp:GridView 
                    ID="gvReports" 
                    runat="server" 
                    CssClass="gridview" 
                    RowStyle-CssClass="gridview_itm" 
                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridview_aitm" 
                    HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview_hdr" 
                    PagerStyle-CssClass="gridview_pgr" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    Width="100%" onrowcommand="gvReports_RowCommand">                
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">                    
                        <ItemTemplate>                        
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReport" runat="server" CommandName="Report" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("n_ReportFileName")%>' Text='<%#Eval("n_Name")%>' CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">                    
                        <ItemTemplate>                        
                            <%#Eval("n_Description")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
            </asp:GridView> 
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="ReportParameterPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True" />                
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="visibility:hidden"/>
            <asp:Panel ID="ReportParameterPanel" runat="server" Height="375px"                     
                Width="700px" BackColor="#f4de90" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Outset" 
                BorderWidth="5px"> 
                <table style="height: 50px; width: 685px; text-align: left">
                    <span id="lblReportName" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:larger"></span>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-left: 5px; width: 335px;" valign="top">
                            <span id="StarDateStar" runat="server" style="color: Red">*Optional&nbsp;</span><span id="lblStartDate" runat="server">Start Date: </span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ceStartDate" runat="server" TargetControlID ="tbStartDate" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar" />        
                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mexStartDate" runat="server" 
                                TargetControlID="tbStartDate" 
                                Mask="99/99/9999" 
                                MaskType="Date"
                                MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
                                OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" />
                                <br />
                            <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevStartDate" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="tbStartDate"
                                ControlExtender="mexStartDate" 
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                InvalidValueMessage="This date is invalid!" Font-Bold="True" 
                                ForeColor="#D50000" ValidationGroup="vgMyGroup" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; width: 350px;" valign="top">
                            <span id="EndDateStar" runat="server" style="color: Red">*Optional&nbsp;</span><span id="lblEndDate" runat="server">End Date: </span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendar2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ceEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID ="tbEndDate" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar2" />        
                            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mexEndDate" runat="server" 
                                TargetControlID="tbEndDate" 
                                Mask="99/99/9999" 
                                MaskType="Date"
                                MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
                                OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" />
                                <br />
                            <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevEndDate" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="tbEndDate"
                                ControlExtender="mexEndDate" 
                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                InvalidValueMessage="This date is invalid!" Font-Bold="True" 
                                ForeColor="#D50000"
                                ValidationGroup="vgMyGroup" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                                                                  
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btn" onclick="btnClose_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Report" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSend_Click" Enabled="false" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="vgMyGroup" />                    
            </asp:Panel>
                </div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling modalpopupextender from codebehind:

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

Comment: That is what I am using from the code behind and also hiding it from code behind but it does not work.

Comment: try keeping ModalPopup inside updatepanel(child) and refresh/update that before calling ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

Comment: Are you saying to have another UpdatePanel and wrap it around ModalPopupExtender and the Panel?

Answer (score 0):

Use LinkButtons instead and on Click clear the controls in the modalpopup, and then call ModalPopup.Show()

Comment: <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="ReportParameterPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True" />                
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="visibility:hidden"/>

Comment: That is how I am initializing the ModalPopupExtender and then I am calling ModalPopupExtender1.show() from code behind and I am also hiding it from code behind but it still keeps the previous values.

Comment: In the codebehind, just before you call ModalPopupExtender1.show(), reinitialize/clear all the controls in the Modalpopup manually.That should do.

Comment: I am trying to see if I could avoid doing manual reinitialize/clear the elements. I know there has to be a way to clear all components under Modal Popup Without Clearing each individual one

Comment: There is no furnished way to clear all the controls on the ModalPopup. You either need to postback and clear them, or you could use JQuery: put a div with an id around your input boxes then the following Jquery will clear the textboxes in your modal.

'$("#commentdata :input").val("");
<div id="commentdata">                                          input textboxes

</div>

'

Comment: Well I have tried <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" and even forcing the PostBack does not re initialize the data. The only thing that seems to work it Response.Redirect back to the page but that's crazy :)

Comment: There is labels that get hidden, there is validators that get enabled and disabled, there is text boxes, there is check boxes that are hidden or checked and unchecked based on a row clicked so that why I am trying to stay away from re-initializing them manually to many controls...